# Data list where clause

Tags: asp.net

i am using a datalist to display videos but i am trying to get it working now with the where clasue ...where the name is equal to wrd.mp4 i am getting the following error,

**$exception    {"The multi-part identifier \"wrd.mp4\" could not be bound."}   System.Exception {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException}**

```
private void BindGrid()
{
    string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "select Id, Name from tblFiles where Name=wrd.mp4";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            DataList1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataList1.DataBind();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use quotes:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select Id, Name from tblFiles where Name='wrd.mp4'";
```

Comment: @user3141831 - I would suggest to accept the answer unless you have any issue with it. Only asking questions and not accepting any answer is not going to help anyone. Please read this:[How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).